# WooCommerce cart page execute request twice

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I have problem with adding products to cart and redirecting to cart page via quick buy form that i made.

I used Contact Form 7 functionality to execute Javascript after form submission:

```
on_submit: 
"var cfq = document.getElementById('product-quantity').value;
 window.location.replace
('http://mywebsite.com/cart/?add-to-cart=310&quantity='+cfq);"
```

Problem is that when im logged-in cart page is adding product for second time, so when my `cfq = 1` i have 2 product in cart, when its equal to 2 i got 4 etc.. Can you suggest how can i improve this solution or maybe some another approach to achieve this effect ?

I also receive double "Your product was added to cart" notification.
When im not logged-in everything seems to work good.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

i can't see what wrong with your script, cause that i think the problem is not in contact from 7. 
so just try open link http://mywebsite.com/cart/?add-to-cart=310&quantity=1
how much product added to your cart?

Comment: I found what was the problem. This problem occurs only when you're logged as admin - when you're not logged-in everything seems to work.  I will modify my question.